# When using vitest to test components, an InvalidCharacterError is reported: "/ src / assets / vue. svg " does not match the name used for production

Tags: vue.js, testing, vitest

An invalidCharacterError is reported: "/ src / assets / vue. svg " does not match the name used for production.But the browser can display the icon normally.

```js
// App.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import VueIcon from '@/assets/vue.svg'
</script>
<template>
  <VueIcon/>
</template>
```

```
// App.spec.ts
import { describe, expect, it } from 'vitest'
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'  
import App from '../src/App.vue'  
describe('App', ()  => {  
  it('mount', async () => {  
    const wrapper = mount(App)
})
```